# Upgrading asp.net web service from windows server 2003(IIS 6.1) to windows server 2012(IIS 8.0)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

We have some .NET web services that were written in vs 2008(framework 2.0) that are currently running in windows 2003 server(IIS).  I had upgraded the ASP.NET web services to target framework 4.6 in vs 2015, and we want to deploy this latest web service to windows server 2012(IIS 8).  When we publish the web service content in IIS 8(windows server 2012), we created a new web site and placed the latest web service content there.  I found that all the web sites in my web server(IIS 8) are only HTTPS web sites.  I tried to create an HTTPS website for my web service but still no luck.

When i deployed this web service as a virtual directory under default website, it ran successfully (but it was https only).

I want to make this web service run as a new site not under default website.

Images: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "all the websites are only https"?  Does that mean you can only access them by using [https://yoursite.com](https://yoursite.com) and you cannot access them by using [http://yoursite.com](http://yoursite.com)?

Comment: Hi Jeff, yes the websites currently inside server are all SSL enabled and only we can access them only by using https://example.com not by using http://example.com ... Is there something to do with the IE settings ???